# Cant find >python scraper.py - can't open file 'scraper.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, errno

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bg9r_yLk7VY) - Dev Ed <3
Usually I complete his tutorial with no major problem.. but this one I'm stuck at 4:05 minute mark.

I install all the packages as he does, but when I try to scrape like this :

```
(venv) C:\Users\Mario\PycharmProjects\Bitanga>python scraper.py
```

I get this

> C:\Users\Mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe:
>   can't open file 'scraper.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Why? I have bs4 installed and requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computer can't find `scraper.py`. Check your "C:\Users\Mario\PycharmProjects\Bitanga", is there `scraper.py` there?

Comment: i found C:\Users\Mario\PycharmProjects\Bitanga\venv\Lib\site-packages\scraping-0.0.3.dist-info but no scraper.py

Comment: You just need to re-write Dev Ed's code in your text editor, save it and name it "scraper.py" in folder Bitanga. Then run "python scraper.py" again

Comment: @Bitanga ur welcome. fyi here in stackoverflow, we usually upvote the answer as a thanks. and "accept answer" if it solved our problems.

Comment: I tired, but i have less then 15 upvotes,so i cant cast any votes:)

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the file doesn't exist in that directory. Make sure you're in the correct directory where your file is located (e.g. `C:\\Users\Me\Desktop`) using the `cd` command in terminal. You can list the files in the current directory with the `ls` or `dir` command in terminal.

Could also be that your file is named something else. Maybe you have a typo in the file name? Have you saved the file before running it?

Comment: (venv) C:\Users\Mario\PycharmProjects\Bitanga>cd
C:\Users\Mario\PycharmProjects\Bitanga
this is what i got when i typed in CD in terminal

Comment: `cd` stands for Change Directory I believe. It's just a way to navigate through your directory hierarchy in terminal. Run the command `dir` on windows or `ls` on a unix system and see if "scraper.py" shows up there. If not, you can use `cd <folder-to-navigate-to>` to browse around your files to find it. Alternatively, you can just use a file explorer to find the file; then use the `cd` command in terminal to where you found the `scraper.py` file in the file explorer.